# Magento grid view qty box to show minimum qty

Tags: php, magento

I want a QTY box next to the add to cart button in grid category view with the products minimum quantity. I have tried using the code below and it works except that the field always shows a '0'.

How can I make it so that the field shows the minimum quantity of the product and not just '0'.

This is what I used to modify the list.phtml file:

```
                        <?php if(!$_product->isGrouped()): ?>

                        <label for="qty"><?php echo $this->__('Qty:') ?></label>                                 
                                <input name="qty" type="text" class="input-text qty" id="qty" maxlength="12" value="<?php echo $this->getProductDefaultQty() * 1 ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('Qty') ?>" class="input-text qty" />

                        <?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

The function getProductDefaultQty is only available on view block and not the list :(

You could rewrite the class Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List with a customer module and include this function in your module's class.

For the sake of this answer I will call your module Nat_Quantity (you can change this if you like)

**Step 1: Create a moudle xml**

Under /app/etc/modules/ create a file Nat_Quantity.xml. It should look something like (note the codePool has a uppercase P).

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Nat_Quantity>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
            <depends>
                <Mage_Catalog />
            </depends>
        </Nat_Quantity>
    </modules>
</config>
```

**Step 2: Create your modules folder structure**

Under /app/code/local/ create the folder Nat, then under there create the folder Quantity.
Under this Quantity folder create the following two folders, etc and Block. (Note the etc is lowercase)

**Step 3: Create your config.xml**

Under /app/code/local/Nat/Quantity/etc create a config.xml file that will look something like:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Nat_Quantity>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </Nat_Quantity>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <blocks>
            <catalog>
                <rewrite>
                    <product_list>Nat_Quantity_Block_Product_List</product_list>
                </rewrite>
            </catalog>
        </blocks>
    </global>
</config>
```

**Step 3: Create your block**

Under /app/code/local/Nat/Quantity/Block/Product create a List.php which will looks something as follows:

```
<?php
class Nat_Quantity_Block_Product_List extends Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List {
    /**
     * Get default qty - either as preconfigured, or as 1.
     * Also restricts it by minimal qty.
     *
     * @param null|Mage_Catalog_Model_Product
     *
     * @return int|float
     */
    public function getProductDefaultQty($product)
    {
        $qty = $this->getMinimalQty($product);
        $config = $product->getPreconfiguredValues();
        $configQty = $config->getQty();
        if ($configQty > $qty) {
            $qty = $configQty;
        }

        return $qty;
    }
}
```

This should then allow you in the list template to call $this->getProductDefaultQty($product). You will need to pass into the function a validate product or you could pass in a product id and then load the product in the function

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId);
```

Comment: Thanks, excuse me as I don't have much experience but where would I be able to find what I need to modify?

Comment: did this help you with your problem?